# Hash_md5() in not working while merging in Exasol

Tags: sql, merge-statement, exasol

I'm trying to merge and update target table based on Hash_val.
but i'm getting below error.
**Such merge condition is not supported.**
below is the code.

```
merge into table1 as t1 
using table2 as t2
on hash_md5(t1.col1||t1.col2||t1.col3)=hash_md5(t2.col1||t2.col2||t2.col3)
when matched then
update t1.col4='XYZ'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about breaking up the join condition of the merge into it's subparts

```
merge into table1 as t1 
using table2 as t2
on t1.col1=t2.col1
and t1.col2=t2.col2
and t1.col3=t2.col3

when matched then update set t1.col4='XYZ'
```

This should effectively do the same as a join on a concat-single criterion.

Comment: yes, I can do that but  would like to know why it's not working when I'm concatenating.